# Group Android Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, grouping

I am building an Android app and I had a question regarding how Activities can be grouped together. On my app I have 3 buttons, each button is sort of a section or container. One button takes you to a series of sequential activities, another to a list view, and another to few links. What I would like to do is group each section so that it saves it's own state. For instance, on the series of activities, I want to be able to press the button for those, and come back to the last activity in that series of activities, with all the state still in all of those particular activities still there. Same for the second button, I click that and it maintains the data and scroll position for that listview (I pretty much know how to handle this though). It's the series of sequential activities I trying to figure out. Is there some sort of container I can use to group all of those sequential activities? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're searching for is named Fragments on Android, see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: So to make it even more clear, for my "collection" of sequential screens, would all of these be several fragments within one activity?

Comment: This is the usual flow seen in many Apps including Android system Apps, so yes.